# How to save data in directus data model from 3rd part?

Tags: docker, directus, directus-flows

I am working on a Direct us project where I need to integrate data from a third-party API into my Directus database using Node.js. I've reviewed the Directus documentation but this not get solution.

I am facing challenges with the integration. I'm seeking advice on the best practices for integrating external APIs with Directus without sharing code explicitly.

My config file is:

```
   services:
    # Database, Option 1: MySQL Version 5
    database:
        container_name: ${STACK_PRFX}-database
        image: bitnami/mysql:8.0
        # Uncomment for local macOS development
        # platform: linux/amd64
        volumes:
            - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
        env_file:
            - .env

    # Directus
    directus:
        container_name: ${STACK_PRFX}-directus
        image: directus/directus:latest 
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 8055:8055
        volumes:
            - ./uploads:/directus/uploads
            - ./extensions:/directus/extensions
        depends_on:
            - database
        env_file:
            - .env
```